# CSS Hover not working?

Tags: css, hover

I have a short descrption on a menu that I do not want to show until you hover over the menu. I cannot get this to work and not sure why. In my example the intended outcome is the words `My Work` should be hidden initially then on hover the words `My Work` become visible. The hover isn't working.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/2Wrj7/1/) and the code:

***HTML***

```
<ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
            <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
            <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
        </span>
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

***CSS***

```
ul.sdt_menu li .sdt_descr{
   visibility:hidden;
}
ul.sdt_menu li .sdt_descr:hover{
   visibility:visible;
}
```

I do not mind using jQuery if that is a better solution.

Comment: Try that: ul.sdt_menu li .sdt_wrap:hover .sdt_descr

Comment: @mika - That does not work.

Comment: I don't see My Work with or without hover in Chrome

Comment: @IgorJerosimić - It is hidden initially and will become visible on hover, well that is the intended outcome but the hover doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - It controls the menu movement and function. It is not specific to the question but is there to show how to menu properly works.

Comment: **Proper demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8n9K4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
ul.sdt_menu li .sdt_descr:hover{
   visibility:visible;
}
```

put this:

```
ul.sdt_menu li:hover .sdt_descr{
   visibility:visible;
}
```

This will allow you to show description when user hovers the li element. http://jsfiddle.net/2Wrj7/3/

Comment: Thanks, that was my desired results. I actually took an idea from @ozk with opacity, sprinkled some CSS3 and it looks much nicer. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

This is strange behavior (having something hidden until the user hovers it). It's essentially a hidden feature, so potentially a UX problem.

Other than that, the element isn't registering as "hovered" since it is hidden.
You can use `opacity` (and its IE specific counterpart `filter:alpha`) to make the element completely transparent until hovered, giving the desired effect:

```
ul.sdt_menu li .sdt_descr{
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
ul.sdt_menu li .sdt_descr:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

should probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, however, I realized part of my problem. You must hover over the element itself, not just the menu. Thanks for the UX recommendation. In context it works well.